# How can I get some information about crashed program in c++ for future debugging

Tags: c++, c++11, debugging, c++14, error-logging

I would like to know is there any way to capture some information when a program crashes in c++. This information can be used for future debugging by developers. For example, this information provides that my program crashes in which line of code and in which function or preferably why.

Comment: You're probably looking for a crash dump (on Windows sometimes referred to as "Minidump"). They can be used to capture the state of your application and allow you to debug it a later point (including memory, stack traces, exceptions). Take a look at the breakpad (https://chromium.googlesource.com/breakpad/breakpad/) library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`google::InstallFailureSignalHandler();` can provide us the information. It also automatically prints call stack.
It is very easy to use.
For more information please see
http://rpg.ifi.uzh.ch/docs/glog.html

Answer (score 6):

The concept is called a *crash dump* on Windows or *core dump* on Linux. It's not a feature of C++ but of the operating system. It works well for code that was compiled to native assembler instructions (which is often the case for C++).

The state of the crashed program at the time of the crash will be saved, so you can have a look at call stacks, memory, registers etc. The amout of information can be configured. The analysis is then done with the help of a debugger, e.g. [windbg](/questions/tagged/windbg) on Windows.

For line numbers, be aware to build symbols along with your binaries. For the analysis you need to bring the crash dump together with the correct symbols to get the line numbers.

Comment: BTW, here’s my overview article for Windows OS: http://const.me/articles/windbg/windbg-intro.pdf

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get some information about crashed program in c++ for future debugging

## This is implementation specific.

(In practice, both compiler specific and [operating system](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/) specific; I am taking a [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) centered point of view)

### C++11 is a programming language, defined by a specification written in English ([n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)). It is *not* a software.

You usually use some [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) to compile your C++ code. I recommend using a recent version of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) or of [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/). If you use it, compile your C++ code [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) all warnings and debug info, that is with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` or `clang++ -Wall -Wextra -g` at least. Some compilers are capable of optimization while emitting debug information (e.g. you could run `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -Og`, as we do in [RefPerSys](https://refpersys.org/)). You could sometimes also *generate* C++ code with tools like [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/) or [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) -or even some other C++ program- (and such an approach is called [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming)).

Once you compiled your C++ code with [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug information (perhaps also using a build automation tool like [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)), you could (on Linux at least) use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger. Since [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html) can deal with a [core(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) dump (see [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)).

Of course, if you are coding an operating system [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)) in C++ (like [this](https://github.com/wichtounet/thor-os) one), things are different.

Answer (score 0):

Without detracting from what has been said above, i think that you need to build a signal handler which can perform a backtrace to the place in the code where it crushed. something like that

```
void signalHandler(int signal)
{
    void *array[500];
    size_t size;

    // get void*'s for all entries on the stack
    size = backtrace(array, 500);
    // print out all the frames to stderr
    
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: signal %d:\n", signal);
    backtrace_symbols_fd(array, size, STDERR_FILENO);
    exit(1);
}


void registerSignalHandler()
{
    signal(SIGSEGV, signalHandler);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    registerSignalHandler();
    
   // your code 
   return 1;
}
```